# getting values from table and looking them for url values

Tags: javascript, html, vba, excel

okay so i am looking to scrap some dating from a web page and i cant seem to make it dynamic.

I need to lookup an element tag "th" that has a value of "level" and then grab the corresponding "td" element tag

This information is coming from an html table with a hiarchy of:

```
{table
-tbody
--tr
---th
---td
--tr
---th
---td}
```

here is the start of my code:

```
{
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Row = Range("link").Row And _
  Target.Column = Range("link").Column Then
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate Range("link").Value
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set doc = ie.document
    Dim sTR As String
    sTR = doc.getElementsByTagName("th")(5).textContent
    MsgBox sTR            
 End If  
End Sub
}
```

I get this far but I have found that the "th" dosnt match every webpage that i am looking for. sometimes "th" 5 dosnt have the same value that i need.